# Can a CoroutineWorker schedule another worker?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I would like to schedule another job with a worker. But, I couldn't find in the doc if that is allowed or not.

Something like:

```kotlin
class MyWorker(context: Context, params: WorkerParameters): CoroutineWorker(context, params) {

    override val coroutineContext = Dispatchers.IO

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result = coroutineScope {
        val syncWorker = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<MyWorker>()
            .setInitialDelay(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build()

        WorkManager.getInstance(context)
            .enqueueUniqueWork("MyJob", ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE, syncWorker)
        Result.success()
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, with one exception.

The only case that can be dangerous is if you are enqueuing an unique worker with a `ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE` from an instance of the same worker (taking your example, you cannot reschedule the work from the same `syncWorker`):

```
class syncWorker(context: Context, params: WorkerParameters): CoroutineWorker(context, params) {

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val syncWorker = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<MyWorker>()
                .build()

            // DON'T DO THIS!!!
            // You may end up with two instances of the same worker
            // running at the same time
            WorkManager.getInstance(context)
                .enqueueUniqueWork("MyJob", ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE, syncWorker)
            Result.success()
        }   
    }
}
```

Also note that `coroutineContext` [is now deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/work/CoroutineWorker#coroutineContext:kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineDispatcher). Use instead `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` like show in my snippets.

Comment: So, I must have at least 2 Workers, one for making this manual schedule?

Comment: Also, if I use KEEP, instead of REPLACE, I will avoid the chance of having 2 instances of the same worker running at the same time?

Comment: Using `ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP` avoids that a worker is rescheduled if it has already been scheduled and it is not in a final state. Regarding your first question. As I said, you may have a problem if you enqueue a unique worker from another instance of the same worker. From the code you posted in your initial question, this was not the case.